# making a map in java in which third key value will be changed in every iteration

Tags: java

I have created a map which will ultimately drop a message to queue that is the message drop to the queue is of map type now but rite now the map contain of the below key value pairs

```
Map(<String , String >) rmap = new HashMap(<String , String >);
    rmap.put(ID, 750);
    rmap.put(FILELOC,"C:\\ta\\");
    rmap.put(FILENAMES,"wer.xls");
```

now the problem with the above map is that it is fo a single file rite now lets say for 10 different files shown below

```
abc.xls
ert.xlsx
gftr.xls
ewrt.xlsx
fdre.xls
saww.xls
hyt.xls
qwer.xls
erty.xls
uhc.xls
```

now i want that an loop to be called above map in which first two key values  will remain same that is ID , FILELOC will remain same for all above 10 files but the last key FILENAMES value  will be change
one way to achieve is that i have created a list for the third property of map but i do not wish to do that , please advise how can i put a loop in map in which it first two properties will remain same

and the third key FILENAMES value will be change some thing like this

```
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"abc.xls");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"ert.xlsx");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"gftr.xls");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"ewrt.xlsx");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"fdre.xls");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"saww.xls");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"hyt.xls");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"qwer.xls");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"erty.xls");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"uhc.xls");
```

Comment: It appears you should be using an object rather than a map.  Since you are adding this map repeatedly to a queue, most likely you need to copy the map rather than repeatedly altering the same one.  I suggest you just re-create the map, this will be simpler and less error prone.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Thanks a lot but can you show a little bit as I have done please that will help to grasp more Thanks in advance what i grasp is to create two sepratae maps

Comment: You have to be aware that assigning different values to the same key of a map overwrites all of them except the last one. What is expected the FILENAMES entry to contain? One single value of several values?

Comment: What you should do instead exactly depends on what you are trying to do. When developers use a Map like this it almost certainly is an example of object denial. I.e. you should be using a class instead.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks a lot but please suggest any alternative way by which i can achieve it please

Comment: I assume you know what a class is as it a basic principle of object orientated programming.  I would have one field per key you have now, make then all final and set them in your constructor.  You can use your IDE to generate most of the code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey well i agree to your advise please I ahve cretaed a seprate class and i will create a map that will be of my this class type but then also i have to create seprate maps holiding the different values rite

Comment: You need with a class instance which has a field which is a `Set<String>` or you need a List of you class instance.  I don't see how using a Map is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you want to do. But you could use [Guava's Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) which allows you to associate a key with multiple values

```
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;

Multimap<String, String> rmap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
rmap.put(ID, String.valueOf(750)) ;
rmap.put(FILELOC,"C:\\ta\\");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"wer.xls");
//....
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"uhc.xls");
// loop FILENAMES
for (String filename : rmap.get(FILENAMES))
    process(filename);
```

Comment: If you post code, the please check that it would actually work.